# Identifying and Removing Vertices after Cut Routine via Python

Tags: python, mesh

I am looking to solve an issue created after a Boolean cut routine through scripting. I run a cut routine between 2 objects in the scene. On the object being cut, several additional vertices are added to the mesh being cut that don’t exist in the cutting object. I expect this as a result. I would like to try and identify these points via Python and, I think, dissolve the vertice and split the face (bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_verts(use_face_split=True).

The one image shows how most vertices will share a similar position with the cutting mesh. But, the additional vertices will be “singles”.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: This image is the 2 vertices I want removed (grey and green meshes are separate objects)]

[image: This is showing the single vertice and the other location where vertices are sharing a similar position]

[image: This is the result I would like for each of the "single vertices"]

The following is the cutting loop that I am using for the meshes. The meshes are essentially planes cutting out planes - hence the Solidify modifier. Perhaps, this is a messy solution. It works really well except for a few bad vertices per mesh.

```
#essentiaally looping over every object aand cutting to layers that are greater than itself
#I expect that the object being cut out would have the same exact verts
#Cut meshes according to hierarchy order
        for rngIndex in range(99):
            hole = str(rngIndex).zfill(2)
            print('Working on Hole ' + str(hole))

            index = 0
            for mesh in bpy.context.scene.objects:
                if ('Hole' + str(hole)) in mesh.name:
                    print("Applying cuts to " + mesh.name)
                    
                    ourItemOfConcern = index + 1
                    
                    for cutter in bpy.context.selected_objects[ourItemOfConcern:]:
                        if ('Hole' + str(hole)) in cutter.name:
                            
                            tempCutter = cutter.copy()
                            me = tempCutter.data
                            
                            solidify = tempCutter.modifiers.new("Solidify", 'SOLIDIFY')
                            solidify.offset = 0.0
                            solidify.thickness = 1
                            solidify.use_flip_normals = False
                            solidify.use_even_offset = False
                            solidify.use_quality_normals = True
                            solidify.use_rim = True
                            solidify.use_rim_only = False

                            
                            bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
                            
                            obj_modifier = mesh.modifiers.new('cutterModifier', 'BOOLEAN')
                            obj_modifier.object = tempCutter
                            obj_modifier.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'

                            
                            bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
                            
                            me = mesh.data
                            
                            print('Cutting out' + cutter.name)
                    
                index += 1
                
#This is some crude loop testing
#but, the end result of the loop is that 335 verts in layer1 are not present in layer0. 
#total layer1 vert counts is 1000+, so many of them match up perfect. But, for some reason, 335 do not.

#Cleaing up orphaned verts
        globalVerts = []
        layer0Verts = []
        layer1Verts = []
        
        #this for loop is simply getting all the verts 
        #something seems weird here though. I feel like when we throw it into edit mode, 
        #it is changing where the vert is. maybe....?
        counter=0
        for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            obj.select_set(True)
                
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
            
            print(obj.name)
            me = obj.data
            
            print('looping verts')
            for i in me.vertices:
                obMat = obj.matrix_world
                wCoords=obMat @ i.co
                #wCoords.x=truncateCoords(wCoords.x)
                #wCoords.y=truncateCoords(wCoords.y)
                #wCoords.z=0
                globalVerts.append(wCoords)
                
                if counter == 0:
                    #print(wCoords)
                    layer0Verts.append(wCoords)
                if counter == 1:
                    #print(wCoords)
                    layer1Verts.append(wCoords)
                
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()   
            
            counter+=1  
            
        print("Layer 0  Verts: " + repr(len(layer0Verts)))
        print("Layer 1  Verts: " + repr(len(layer1Verts)))
        
        missingLayerVerts=0
        for thisVert in layer1Verts:
            if thisVert not in layer0Verts:
                missingLayerVerts+=1
                
        print("Missing layer 1 verts: " + str(missingLayerVerts))
```

Comment: Easier for others to help if you show code used.

Comment: No problem. I added that code to the original question via an EDIT.